# Is there a word that describes a Port and Protocol combination

Tags: network

I am just looking to see if there is a word that describes a port and protocol combination. In the same way that the word socket refers to a IpAddress and Port combination. Is there a similar term to describe a Protocol and Port combination?

Comment: A port is an address for some transport protocols. TCP, UDP, SCTP, etc. use the term port for an address in the protocol. Other transport protocols may use other or no addressing. Remember that a port only has meaning in the context of the transport protocol, e.g. TCP port 12345 is not UDP port 12345, The transport protocols may use the same number range (16 bits is a convenient address length), but even ports of the same number are different with different transport protocols.

Comment: IANA (Internet Assigned Numbers Authority) calls it "_Transport Protocol Port Number_" in its registry, and it will assign port numbers in the range of each transport protocol (really `0` to `65565` because each transport protocol uses a 16-bit unsigned integer for its port numbers) to the transport protocol.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you're aiming at, but a *well-known port* may be what you're looking for. It's the default port number for any application-layer protocol.

Incidentally, a socket refers to an IP address, *transport-layer protocol* and port number combination. That is, the same port numbers for TCP and UDP do *not* describe the same socket.

Comment: Actually "socket" is a much lower level construct. The manpage just says *create an endpoint for communication*. Any number of protocols my be used... ipv4, ipv6, ipx, appletalk, x25, atm, ...

Comment: @Ricky Agreed, generally. A socket is a transport-layer concept (in the on-topic sense, *not* the API sense). I was - somewhat wildly - assuming the OP referred to *application-layer* protocols which may be wrong. Your list refers to network-layer protocols, but we don't have any ports there.

Answer (score 0):

In computer networking, the closest term is a *network socket*, or simply *socket*, as the most popular networking protocols use *well known port* numbers. In other words, the port number itself signifies the protocol.

> Network sockets may be dedicated for persistent connections for
> communication between two nodes, or they may participate in
> connectionless and multicast communications.
>
> #### Definition
>
> The distinctions between a socket (internal representation), socket descriptor (abstract identifier), and socket
> address (public address) are subtle, and these are not always
> distinguished in everyday usage. Further, specific definitions of a
> socket differ between authors. In IETF Request for Comments, Internet
> Standards, in many textbooks, as well as in this article, the term
> socket refers to an entity that is uniquely identified by the socket
> number. In other textbooks,[1] the term socket refers to a local
> socket address, i.e. a "combination of an IP address and a port
> number". In the original definition of socket given in RFC 147,[2] as
> it was related to the ARPA network in 1971, "the socket is specified
> as a 32 bit number with even sockets identifying receiving sockets and
> odd sockets identifying sending sockets." Today, however, socket
> communications are bidirectional.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_socket